# Print array of array of array of array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$elementos[$n]['fabricante'] = array($arr3[text][0]);
$elementos[$n]['titulo'] = array($arr[text][0]);
$elementos[$n]['descripcion'] = array($arr2[text][0]);
```

But I can find a way to show the content of this array.

I get the word Array o a empty text.

Please I have 2 days with this problem. Help

This is the information in the $elementos array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [fabricante] => Array ( [0] => Cisco ) [codigo] => Array ( [0] => ICND1 ) [titulo] => Array ( [0] => Interconnecting Cisco Network Devices I ) [descripcion] => Array ( [0] => Este curso se enfoca en proporcionar las habilidades y conocimientos necesarios para instalar, operar y localizar fallas en una red empresarial pequeña de sucursal, incluyendo configurar un conmutador, un enrutador y conectar a una WAN e implementar la seguridad de la red. El Participante debe poder completar la configuración e implementación de una pequeña red de oficina sucursal con supervisión. ) ) [1] => Array ( [fabricante] => Array ( [0] => Cisco ) [codigo] => Array ( [0] => ICND2 ) [titulo] => Array ( [0] => Interconnecting Cisco Network Devices II ) [descripcion] => Array ( [0] => Este curso se enfoca en proporcionar las habilidades y conocimientos necesarios para instalar, operar y localizar fallas en una red empresarial de tamaño medio para una sucursal, incluyendo la configuración de conmutadores de datos y enrutadores, además de conectar la red LAN a una WAN e implementar seguridad ) ) )
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague and incomplete, and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: dont post an array dump as a single line...its hard for us to read just like it is for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a few different ways.

To inspect the array you can

```
echo "<pre>"; // for readability on the browser
print_r( $elementos );
```

To view the types of the data in the array

```
echo "<pre>"; // for readability on the browser
var_dump( $elementos );
```

You could also display the array in JSON, which is useful in some scenarios:

```
echo json_encode( $elementos );
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

For your example, use this

```
echo "<pre>";    
print_r($elementos);
echo "</pre>";
```

print_r() is used for printing arrays. Useful thing to remember!

That's if your using php of course!

EDIT: Just saw your tag, of course your using PHP

Answer (score -2):

You can use foreach inside of foreach a few times.

Comment: That doesn't really explain much does it.